# How does where clause process tuples

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm curious to understand how WHERE clause exactly works. For instance, let's take 3 tables:

**Tables**

```
Teacher(*t_code*, name, age)
Subject(*s_code*, name, course)
Teaches(*t_code*, *s_code*)
```

If I do

**Query**

```
SELECT Teacher.name FROM Teacher, Subject, Teaches
WHERE Teacher.t_code = Teaches.t_code
AND Teaches.s_code = Subject.s_code;
```

I retrieve teacher's name for each different subject it's teaching. However, I don't get it how the WHERE clause does it. At the first condition, I see that only teachers who are assigned to at least one subject will be kept. Then, the same thing happens to the Subject table. Subjects who are not being teached are discarded. In the end, the query knows exactly where each subject belong to the correct teacher. My question is: how is it processing each tuple to retrieve the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` Statement

ex-:

```
SELECT Teacher.name FROM Teacher, Subject, Teaches
WHERE Teacher.t_code = Teaches.t_code
AND Teaches.s_code = Subject.s_code GROUP BY Subject.course;
```